# Generating tiered bullet lists in SPARX Enterprise Architect

Tags: reporting, rtf, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to create a RTF report which shows a heirarchy of user stories. In my model I have the following package structure:

```
Requirements Package
- Package A
- - Requirement 1
- - Requirement 2
- - Requirement 3
- Package B
- - Sub-Package I
- - - Requirement 4
- - - Requirement 5
- - Sub-Package II
- - - Requirement 6
- - - Requirement 7
- Package C
```

I want it to have it come out as a bulleted list like so:

- Package A

  - Requirement 1
  - Requirement 2
  - Requirement 3
- Package B

  - Sub-Package I

    - Requirement 4
    - Requirement 5
  - Sub-Package II

    - Requirement 6
    - Requirement 7
- Package C

I have it working when when it's just requirements in the package by using the following template:

```
package >
*    {Pkg.Name}
element >
    * {Element.Name}
< element
child packages >
< child packages
< package
```

But it "flattens" all the packages as if the sub-packages were under the main requirements package. How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you literally using asterisks as shown in your excerpt, or RFT bullets? If bullets, do you have a multi-level list defined for the bullets?

Comment: I'm using RTF bullets (I just couldn't figure how to show those in the code snippet there). I'm not sure if I have a multi-level list defined- where is that set?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the only way you can do this is to make your package and element names into level 1 and 2 headings, and define stylesheet where you update the styles for numbered headings into bullets.

Child packages/elements don't seem to increase the indent levels or update other numbered styles (I tried creating a bullet1 and bullet2 style, but bullet1 remained bullet1 despite being in a child package).

The options dialog shows a heading level you can increase up-to, and so it would appear that this *only* applies to HeadingX styles.